# After deleting data from a table and performing autovacuum, its size does not decrease

Tags: postgresql

We have a very large table that changes data frequently and deletes records, but its size does not match the actual data stored in the table. I know that the table has an additional fill factor that controls how much data is filled on the page, but shouldn't Postgres insert new data into the freed space after deleting data from the table? Is there a way to reorganize the data in a table? Something like a reindex command for indexes.

Comment: Only `vacuum full` will reduce the size on disk.

Comment: "shouldn't Postgres insert new data into the freed space"  Yes, it should.  What makes you think it doesn't?  And what does this have to do with your title?

Comment: @jjanes, there were doubts related to the fact that the freed up disk space after deleting records was not used